# Astronaut with Jet Engines: Applied Forces and Angular Momentum over Time

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

Let's say that we have an astronaut in space of length $L$ and mass $m$:

[image]

Because of some truly irresponsible space agency, they've attached jet engines to this fellow's arms as depicted in the picture. Assuming that our astronaut will stay completely rigid in his or her composure, such that in their non-intertial frame of reference the force applied by the jet engine will always come from the same angle, and assuming that said force is a function of time, $F=F(t)$, then if the astronaut starts at rest at $t=0$ and is oriented such that their head and feet lie along the vertical line, then at time $t=t_1$, what is the angle that the astronaut is oriented in relative to the vertical line?

[image]

It's been a while since I did my old university courses in classical mechanics. There was a time when I *should* have been able to do these sorts of questions with only minor difficulties, but alas, those days are now long in past.

If you fine people could help me derustify myself by telling me how to solve this problem, I'd be very much grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend $\vec F$ into a long line. Since this long line includes $\ell_2$ in it, the length of $\ell_2$ does not matter at all. I want to find the intersection of this long line with the extended line of $\ell_0$, so that I will be able to find a convenient expression of the torque of $\vec F$ around the centre of mass of the astronaut.

By drawing triangles, this intersection point is above the centre of mass by a length of
$$ \left ( \ell_0 - \ell_1 \cos \theta \right ) + \frac{\ell_1 \sin \theta}{\tan \phi}$$
and since this is vertical, the only component of the force $\vec F$ contributing to the torque calculation is thus the horizontal component, i.e. $\left | \vec F \right | \sin \phi$

We now have all the required ingredients to put into the rotational version of Newton's $2^\text{nd}$ Law,
$$\text{rN2L}\ : \qquad \left [ \ell_0 - \ell_1 \cos \theta + \frac{\ell_1 \sin \theta}{\tan \phi} \right ] \left | \vec F \right | \sin \phi = I \ddot \varphi$$
$$\ddot \varphi = \frac1I \left | \vec F \right | 
\left [ \left ( \ell_0 - \ell_1 \cos \theta \right ) \sin \phi + \ell_1 \sin \theta \cos \phi \right ] \\
\ddot \varphi = \frac1I \left | \vec F \right | \left [ \ell_0 \sin \phi 
+ \ell_1 \sin \left ( \theta - \phi \right ) \right ]$$
which is now ripe to be solved with the initial conditions
$$ \varphi = 0 = \dot \varphi $$
You do, however, have to remember that the moment of inertia $I$ is not as easy to define as $m L^2$ because you have to integrate to get the constant numerical factor in front of it.

Edit: If you want to see why the length dependence is as it is, draw a line parallel to $\ell_2$ between $\ell_0$ and $\ell_1$, and see that the parallel displacement of $\vec F$ due to $\ell_0$ is the first term, whereas the same for $\ell_1$ is the other term. Note that, in general, the perpendicular length displaced will **not** meet up---the line joining the intersection of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ with the centre of mass will not be perpendicular to $\vec F$, and instead may be some parallel length to $\vec F$ away from being perpendicular.